# Generate df from an input dictionary by checking specified 8 conditions in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary as shown below.

```
d1 = { 'start_date' : '2020-10-01T20:00:00.000Z',
       'end_date'  : '2020-10-05T20:00:00.000Z',
       'n_days'    : 6,
       'type'      : 'linear',
       "coef": [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1] 
     }
```

d1: is the input from user, user may enter wrong start_date, end_date and n_days.

we have to replace `end_date = start_date + n_days`

There might be a case where, `start_date`, `end_date` and `n_days` are not available.
non availability specified by `start_date = 0, end_date = 0, n_days = 0`.

Then we will have 8 conditions

```
1. if (start_date != 0) and (end_date != 0) and (n_days != 0):
          end_date = start_date + n_days

2. if (start_date != 0) and (end_date != 0) and (n_days == 0):
          pass
    
3. if (start_date != 0) and (end_date == 0) and (n_days != 0):
          end_date = start_date + n_days

4. if (start_date != 0) and (end_date == 0) and (n_days == 0):
          print("Please enter required inputs")

5. if (start_date == 0) and (end_date != 0) and (n_days != 0):
          start_date = end_date - n_days

6. if (start_date == 0) and (end_date != 0) and (n_days == 0):
          print("Please enter required inputs")

7. if (start_date == 0) and (end_date == 0) and (n_days != 0):
          print("Please enter required inputs")

8. if (start_date == 0) and (end_date == 0) and (n_days == 0):
          print("Please enter required inputs")
```

I would like to incorporate all the above conditions by checking the d1.
After that I would like to prepare below df from the above processed d1.

From the above, dictionary as input to the function, I would like to generate below df as output.

Expected output:

df:

```
Date                Day           function_type         function_value
2020-10-01          1             linear                (0.1*1)+0.1 = 0.2
2020-10-02          2             linear                (0.1*2)+0.1 = 0.3
2020-10-03          3             linear                (0.1*3)+0.1 = 0.4
2020-10-04          4             linear                (0.1*4)+0.1 = 0.5
2020-10-05          5             linear                (0.1*5)+0.1 = 0.6
```

Note:

The type can be linear, constant, polynomial and exponential.

```
a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 = d1['coef']

If constant, funtion_value = a0

If exponential funtion_value = e**(a0+a1T)

if polynomial
funtion_value = a0+a1T+a2(T**2)+a3(T**3)+a4(T**4)+a5(T**5)

T = value of Day column
```

Similar question is well answered by @Shubham Sharma and @Let's try
[Generate dataframe based on specific condition and input dictionary - pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575102/generate-dataframe-based-on-specific-condition-and-input-dictionary-pandas/63576261#63575102)

Thank you so much @Shubham Sharma and @Let's try

Comment: @Shubham Sharma Please help me to solve this question

Comment: are you asking how to build a UI that only accepts valid inputs, or how to build DF once you have valid inputs?  These are two different solution spaces

Comment: @RobRaymond if we dont have valid input just sent a message. If we have valid input just prepare the required df

Comment: there's a reason for multi-tier micro services architectures.  don't pollute core processing with validation that belongs on UI.   anything else just leads to unmaintainable solutions.  btw what happens if your list is inconsistent length to dates?  seems like an overall design review required before writing code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending my [`previous answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63576261/12833166) to the [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575102/generate-dataframe-based-on-specific-condition-and-input-dictionary-pandas/63576261#63575102), we can create a custom `validation` fuction that takes the input parameter as the dictionary provided by the user and returns a two pair `tuple` with valid `start_date` and `end_date` otherwise raise an `ValueError`:

```
def validate(d):
    n_days, start, end = d['n_days'], d['start_date'], d['end_date']

    if start == 0:
        if end != 0 and n_days != 0:
            end = pd.to_datetime(end)
            start = end - pd.Timedelta(days=n_days)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid user input')
    else:
        start = pd.to_datetime(start)
        if end != 0 and n_days != 0:
            end = pd.to_datetime(end)
        elif end == 0 and n_days == 0:
            raise ValueError('Invalid user input')
        else:
            end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=n_days)

    return start.tz_localize(None).floor('D'),\
                 end.tz_localize(None).floor('D')
```

and then modify the `getDF` function from the [`previous answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63576261/12833166) and include a `try-except` statement to catch `ValueError` if any:

```
def getDF(d):
    try:
        start, end = validate(d)
        date = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D')
        days = (date - date[0]).days + 1
        return pd.DataFrame({'Date': date, 'Day': days, 'function_type': d['type'],
                            'function_value': funcValue(d, days)})
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
```

Result:

```
print(getDF(d1))

        Date  Day function_type  function_value
0 2020-10-01    1        linear             0.2
1 2020-10-02    2        linear             0.3
2 2020-10-03    3        linear             0.4
3 2020-10-04    4        linear             0.5
4 2020-10-05    5        linear             0.6
```

Comment: pls look into below question, similar question, no one answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580108/iterate-any-of-the-two-elements-in-the-dictionary-of-the-list?noredirect=1#comment112429858_63580108

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @RobRaymond in the comments you need to spend some time thinking about your approach to this problem.

You want to:

1. Accept user input
2. Check that user input is valid
3. Create a dataframe

Write the code for each of those steps separately, if you have questions/problems open a specific question for each individual problem (the more specific the problem the easier it is to provide specific answers).

After you accept user input, store values in a `dict` or `list`. You can then write a separate function (or class method) to for validation. I would recommend initialising the values you expect the user to input (`start_date`, `end_date` etc.) to `None` to allow for cases where the user inputs a 0 or something that's evaluated to a zero. You can then easily check which values are `None`, check whether valid dates have been enter and so on, and write some logic to throw an error or come up with your values etc.

Once you've done that it should be straight forward to make your dataframe. Using the approach above will allow you to debug your code more easily and to add features (or things that you missed) for example if a user enters `06/08/20` is that the 6th of August or the 8th of June? What should happen if the `start_date` occurs after the `end_date`? Or if a user enters `20000`?