# Iterate any of the two elements in the dictionary of the list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary as shown below

```
d4 = {
    "blue": 
        [
          {
              "type": "linear",
              "start_date": "2020-10-01T20:00:00.000Z",
              "end_date": "2020-10-20T20:00:00.000Z",
              "n_days":3,
              "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
              "case":"best"
          }]}
```

Or

```
d5 = {
    "white": 
        [
          {
              "type": "linear",
              "start_date": "2020-10-01T20:00:00.000Z",
              "end_date": "2020-10-20T20:00:00.000Z",
              "n_days":3,
              "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
              "case":"best"
          }]}
```

Input to my function can be d4 or d5.

There might be a case where, start_date, end_date and n_days are not available. non availability specified by start_date = 0, end_date = 0, n_days = 0.

To tackle that we have to apply below 8 conditions.

Then we will have 8 conditions

```
1. if (start_date != 0) and (end_date != 0) and (n_days != 0):
          end_date = start_date + n_days

2. if (start_date != 0) and (end_date != 0) and (n_days == 0):
          pass
    
3. if (start_date != 0) and (end_date == 0) and (n_days != 0):
          end_date = start_date + n_days

4. if (start_date != 0) and (end_date == 0) and (n_days == 0):
          print("Please enter required inputs")

5. if (start_date == 0) and (end_date != 0) and (n_days != 0):
          start_date = end_date - n_days

6. if (start_date == 0) and (end_date != 0) and (n_days == 0):
          print("Please enter required inputs")

7. if (start_date == 0) and (end_date == 0) and (n_days != 0):
          print("Please enter required inputs")

8. if (start_date == 0) and (end_date == 0) and (n_days == 0):
          print("Please enter required inputs")
```

By applying above condition I would like find out the end_date and start_date.

I Tried below code:

```
def validate(d):
    REQUIRED_KEYS = ["blue", "white"]
    for bluewhite_category in REQUIRED_KEYS[0] or REQUIRED_KEYS[1]:
        #print(bluewhite_category)
        if bluewhite_category in REQUEST_OBJ.keys():
            param_obj_list = REQUEST_OBJ[bluewhite_category]
            n_days, start, end = param_obj_list['n_days'], 
                                 param_obj_list['start_date'], 
                                 param_obj_list['end_date']

            if start == 0:
                if end != 0 and n_days != 0:
                    end = pd.to_datetime(end).tz_localize(None).floor('D')
                    start = end - pd.Timedelta(days=n_days)
                else:
                    raise ValueError('Invalid user input')
            else:
                start = pd.to_datetime(start).tz_localize(None).floor('D')
                if end != 0 and n_days != 0:
                    end = pd.to_datetime(end).tz_localize(None).floor('D')
                    end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=n_days)
                elif end == 0 and n_days == 0:
                    raise ValueError('Invalid user input')
                else:
                    end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=n_days)
    
            return start, end
       else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid user input')
```

But above code does not work.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma pls help me to solve this

Comment: why tag pandas ?

Comment: @BEN_YO removed that tags

Comment: He has used `pd.Timedelta` maybe that's why. But, you are right, tags must be related to what the question is about, not what the question contains.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal  should I add pandas tag?

Comment: @BEN_YO Should I add pandas tag?

Comment: @Danish datetime have timedelta like function as well

Comment: @Danish, no need for that. As Ben suggested, there are other libraries for handling date time data and thats not the core of the question to begin with.

Comment: @BEN_YO Ok, agreed

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Ok, noted

Comment: Aside from bickering about tags, what is not working with the code?  You have an equation with 3 unknowns.  If you have data for 2 of them the 3rd is calculable.

Comment: @AirSquid The code is working for pure dictionary, code should work for both d4 and d5. if pass d4, then also code should work. if I pass d5 as input the also the code should work.

Comment: _"Doesn't work"_ what doesn't work? If your car has a broken headlight do you take it to a mechanic and say "my car doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1):

When posting code that "doesn't work" it is extremely helpful to include the error trace or specifics about what isn't working.

That said, this is a problem:

```
REQUIRED_KEYS = ["blue", "white"]
for bluewhite_category in REQUIRED_KEYS[0] or REQUIRED_KEYS[1]:
    #print(bluewhite_category)
    if bluewhite_category in REQUEST_OBJ.keys():
        param_obj_list = REQUEST_OBJ[bluewhite_category]
```

the structure:

```
for x in a or b:
```

is not doing what you hoped for.  Use the `in` function with a list or collection.

Also, `REQUEST_OBJ` is not defined.  Should it be an input to the function?